# reactjs: Es6 unable to understand the syntax

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hook-form

I am using react hook forms and encountered this example of using Controller for material ui TextField

```
({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...field}
                    inputRef={ref}
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    label="Current Password"
                    type="password"
                    margin="dense"
                  />
                )
```

What does the below mean

```
({ field: { ref, ...field } })
```

and also `{...field}` (what it expands to)

```
                  <TextField
                    {...field}
                    inputRef={ref}
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    label="Current Password"
                    type="password"
                    margin="dense"
                  />
```

The total code is

```
              <Controller
                name="old_password"
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...field}
                    inputRef={ref}
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    label="Current Password"
                    type="password"
                    margin="dense"
                  />
                )}
              />
```

Comment: It's de-structuring an object into a variable called `ref` and assigns `obj.field.ref` as a value and takes all the rest that is in the object of `obj.field` minus the `ref` key and assigns that to the variable `field`. The `{...field}` JSX syntax just means it spreads the object onto the component via props

Comment: `obj.field minus the ref key `: didnt get this part

Comment: Well everything in the object minus the `ref` key... So If you had an object like this: `{ ref: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }` and did `const { ref, ...field } = obj` then your `ref` is `1` and `field` is `{ two: 2, three: 3 }`

Comment: Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: so in `const { ref, ...field } = obj`  - `field` is just a representation or variable name. I am more comfortable with seeing the obj i.e `const { ref, ...obj } = obj`

Comment: `field` in that example is just the name of the variable. You can name it whatever you want. You second example would reassign something to the variable you're deconstructing and that's not a good idea as it would mutate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's jus't a regular component... Think about it like this:

```
const Component = (props) =>{
    const {ref, ...field} = props.field
    return(
          <TextField
            {...field}
            inputRef={ref}
            fullWidth
            required
            label="Current Password"
            type="password"
            margin="dense"
          />
    )
}
```

`...field` is just the spreaded original field `props.field` with `ref` property subtracted. In this case necessary cause `TextField` expects a ref to be hold by `inputRef`

Comment: `props.field minus ref property` : can you explain with more breakup